# AWS GLUE: Join conditions will not save. column renaming will not save. Catastrophic

Tags: aws-glue

I've got a glue job that's essentially a core table script and ill save it, all the nodes will have the green checkmark, then ill reload the job and not only do all the join on conditions just clear, the names go back from having a prefix to having overlapping names (ie both tables have a checksum column). I know I've got to be missing something here cause I can't be the only one who's tried to do this.

I have tried making a new job.